# SQL tables, columns and consistency

Tags: mysql

Originating from the IBM DB/400 world, you had a reference Database which one could refer to thus ensuring that for example a column `email` always had the same column length, description or more generally same attributes through out.

I did research, but that ability doesn't seem to exist in MySQL.

So my question would be what method or tools you employ to ensure that a column always has the same attributes within your database.

Obviously one can run a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema='DatabaseTable' order by column_name;
```

which would list them in nice order and then do the labor of adjusting what is not quite consistent.

But being somewhat spoiled, I wonder if there isn't a better way.

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of.  The system tables are the only thing I can think of but you already pointed those out.  The challenge is how do you know what tables would have the same column?  I mean the names of each column in each table would be different, and since you attempt to design a database to eliminate duplication of data; email should only be in one place with FK references to other tables when needed; unless you're looking to retain history/transaction; then I could understand keeping a copy of the email.... So no, not without parsing though the schema columns.

Comment: No, MySQL does not have a user-defined type feature. If you could switch to PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, you could use its feature: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html

Comment: MySQL Workbench has a feature to define user types in the model editor, but it's only an overlay used in the model designer within Workbench. If you execute that model in MySQL Server, your user type is replaced with the underlying type.

Comment: @xQbert. Nope. You can have eMail in various Tables, just like an Amount or Total field. The Table -> Customer.eMail or Employee.eMail makes the difference, however, the Column length should be the same as (and I haven't looked it up yet) Servers will have a limitation on the Length. Likewise you can have Amounts in various Tables, specially in the Accounting area. But you might want to make sure (or I want) that they are always (10.2) or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @Bill Thanks, appreciated, but not exactly what I am looking for. I might end up just creating a Reference Table, list that Content in a HTML Table, click the fields I want for a new Table and then create it from there. Not perfect, but better than Nada.

Comment: I just ran across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843800/mysql-one-column-referenced-to-multiple-table is this what you're tying to do?  I've not done this personally...  perhaps you're after domains? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693991/create-domain-in-mysql which isn't supported in mysql?

Comment: @xQBert. I saw that too. No, I don't want a foreign key. I only want to create a new Table and use a Reference Table for the Field (Column) attributes. I left programming a long time ago and I am actually AS/400 (subsequently DB/400) certified by IBM. You really got spoiled by that. i never understood what a DB/400 Admin would do all day. All you need is schedule a few Jobs that keep the Database in line (Reorg might be one of them, if you have a nasty Table that requires Records in Sequence of Arrival) other than that, you just go home and collect the Pay Check every Month.

Comment: Just to add to this. If anyone knows SAP, they use the same idea. A few reasons. They deal with different SQL Databases, however, the roots are IBM Mainframe. Next to the Subject here, there is one additional issue which is called a Level Check in the IBM world. Every Table has a check sum and that check sum is also part (Reference) of a Compiled Program. If you alter a Table, you might get a new Check sum. Ultimately you your Table check sum and the one stored in the Program might miss match (Change in Buffer length, Field Type etc) and that leads to the Program being unable to execute.

Comment: ... so (run out of space) you get a Level Check and the Program won't execute. Solution that mostly works is to recompile the Program. SAP ABAP does the same. However, it is an Interpreter Language, thus not Compiled, still, they check the Buffer of the Table vs. Program. After all, you can also delete a Column and the Program would possibly fail, leaving your Database in Limbo. On the AS/400 (now iSeries), you can employ a few Tools to deal with that issue and spend your time on the Porch instead of the Office.

Comment: If you have a very good head of Development, that person would employ a check sum feature where a Program or even a script is always doing a Validation between Table and Program to avoid nasty surprises when a Program fails mid execution and screws up your Database consistency. I would endure that 'lack of care' twice before giving that Person an ear full.

Comment: A lot of what you're talking about is no longer necessary, or we have better techniques for. For example, there's no longer a need to add arbitrary restrictions to text fields. `varchar` will use as much space as necessary, so you can just use `varchar(255)` for things which have no inherent length limit like a "subject". There's no need for everything to align perfectly on buffer sizes and types, that's taken care of in the client library. Schema management is done using [schema migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration). Etc.

Comment: @Schwern I don't recall having talked about varchar .... I actually use that all the time. But that is the simple one. As I wrote, different story with numeric fields, if one desires to have them or is forced. It is also one thing to look at a simple Table vs. perhaps SELECT statements used for Reporting and you need to do conversions forth and back to get a calculation done. Not sure if that's opening another can of worms. However, I went with the suggestion of using TimeStamps and that works perfectly and wasn't much of a hassle to implement. As I stated, neat part is ZERO maintenance.

Comment: @Martin I'm really fascinated by how it used to be done in the mainframe days. I don't understand when you say that it's a "*different story with numeric fields, if one desires to have them or is forced*". Nor what you said about simple tables vs select statements and needing to convert. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Schwern My goal is to keep as much flexibility as possible. A data type "blob" is a party pooper no matter what. So when you would design a Grit or anything else, you want to know the data type. For one, adjusting numeric values to the right is a nice thing to do, but when everything is VARCHAR, how would you go about it? Also, you can do complex calculations in SQL and even have the result written to new tables for additional processing.